# Delete duplicate files in array

Tags: windows, powershell, file

I have a folder with duplicate files the first 10-letters in the filename is the same and the last 2 are random, i want to remove these files via PWSH script.
A specific file is located in the same folder where the duplicate files are.
I Don't want to delete this specific file, i only want to delete the duplicate files older then 1 week.

EDIT: I want to delete everything older then 1 week in C:\temp\Folder except from "DontDelete", I want to save that file. (The DontDelete has duplicates as well)

```
$Location = "C:\temp\Folder\" # Here is where all the duplicate files are located
$W = "7" 
$Date = (Get-date).AddDays(-$W)
$DontDelete = "DontDelete*"  
$Array = Get-Content -Path @("C:\Delete\Remove.txt")

Get-ChildItem -Path $Location |
  where { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $Date } |
    Out-file "C:\Delete\Remove.txt" 

Set-Location "$Location" 
$Array 

foreach ($Item in $Array) {
    Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
}

# If $DontDelete exsist in $array (Which it will) don't delete the $Dontdelete file.
# Delete the rest of the files which are older then 7-days.
```

Comment: Based on filename, it is not possible to have duplicate files in same folder. There must be another differentiation parameter

Comment: EDITx2 
"I have a folder with duplicate files the first 10-letters in the filename is the same and the last 2 are random, i want to remove these files via PWSH script. A specific file is located in the same folder where the duplicate files are. I Don't want to delete this specific file, i only want to delete the duplicate files older then 1 week.

EDIT: I want to delete everything older then 1 week in C:\temp\Folder except from "DontDelete", I want to save that file. (The DontDelete has duplicates as well)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to exclude the files located in a(ny) `DontDelete` subdirectory (and its entire subtree) from deletion:

```bash
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File $Location |
  Where-Object LastWriteTime -lt $Date |
  Where-Object FullName -notlike '*\DontDelete\*' |
  Remove-Item -Force -WhatIf
```

Note:

- A single pipeline is used to combine filtering with deletion.
- `Get-ChildItem -Recurse` processes the entire directory *subtree* (not just the immediate child items), and `-File` limits the results to *files* (as opposed to also including *directories*, which is what happens by default).
- The additional [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) call based on `-notlike`, the [negated wildcard matching operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-notlike), is used to filter out files located underneath `DontDelete` subdirectory/ies.
- The result is piped directly to [`Remove-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item); the [**`-WhatIf`** common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#-whatif) in the command above ***previews* the operation**. Remove `-WhatIf` and re-execute once you're sure the operation will do what you want.

Comment: Thanks, this was the answer i was looking for. 
The "DontDelete" folder is saved regardless of "LastWriteTIme" and the duplicates that i wanted to delete got deleted. TYSM!

Answer (score 1):

Im confused as to what your asking but if your asking to just not delete one file. Pipe your Get-Child into a [Where-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7.4) filter

```
$Time = (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)
$Fnd  = "/file/not/to/delete.txt"

Get-ChildItem -Path $Location |
  Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt $Time -and $_.Name -ne $Fnd} |
    Remove-Item -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Then you accomplish everything you asked for in one liner. The initial `Get-Child`, gets all the files in your directory pipes into `Where-Object` which then filters all files older than a week and not your desired file. Which finally pipes into `Remove-Item` which deletes all the items.

Comment: Hi, 
I tried your answer the file got deleted. 
Its not really a Worddocument, its a folder.
This is what i did. 
$Week = (get-date).AddDays(-7)
$Folder = "DontDelete*" #The folder we want to keep
Get-ChildItem -Path $location | ? {$_.LastWriteTime -lt $week -and $_.Name -ne $folder} | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse
And the "DontDelete" got deleted. It was last edited a month ago maybe thats why it was deleted? 
Sorry for my bad england :)

Comment: @Kenturah So your problem could be your using $Folder and not $folder variables are case sensitve. However even if it is a directory it should still recognize it. For kicks you can always run `Get-ChildItem -Path $location` and make sure the  value for $Folder Variable is spelled exactly like the Name is displayed in the column. If its deleting it, its cause the name is not equal. If you changed `-ne` to `-eq` then no item should be deleted which would also prove that the value inside $folder is incorrect

Comment: @KidYume Variables in `PowerShell` are **NOT** case sensitive unless you are dealing with hash table keys. Neither are directory and file names in Windows.

Comment: Good point, @Dennis, but note that if you use `[hashtable]` /  `[System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary]` instances constructed via PowerShell literals (`@{ ... }` / `[ordered] @{ ... }`), their keys are also _not_ case-sensitive; e.g. `@{ foo = 1 }.FOO`

Comment: @KidYume This removes the "DontDelete" folder if its older then 7-days. 
I want to keep the "DontDelete" folder regardless of "LastWriteTime" 
For more context this is how the directory looks like. 
C:\temp\bin
-> Folder1-xx
-> Folder2-xx
-> DontDelete1-xx
-> DontDelete2-xx
:::I want all the "Folder1-xx" "Folder2-xx" "Folder3-xx" that are older then 7 days to get deleted. 
i want to keep the "dontdelete" folders. 
isn't it easier if i do this. 
$Folder1 = "Folder1*" 
$folder2 = "Folder2*" 
Get-childitem -path $location -name $folder1 | ? {$_.LastWriteTime -lt $week} | Remove-item

Comment: @keturah in terms of automation. I would find and put certain properties into the folder you dont want to delete. Down the path you seek you continuously have to change the name of the folders you wish to keep. It does not seem dynamic. Furthermore, what you asked is for a way to keep "DontDelete". I would recommend potentially a name scheme of sorts so instead of `ne` you can use `Contains` 
 $_.Name.Contains("DontDelete"). If a conditional does not meet your needs I think the problem lies in the process. How are you identifying these folders and what can you control?

Comment: @KidYume No worries, its solved. Thanks! 
But now i want to do it with the help of metadata.

Comment: @Kenturah Awesome man. I love to hear it. I highly recommend that path. It will make your life easier and provide means of scalability. especially if you start playing with hundreds of thousands of files. Or you can just run a task and never have to worry about it again. The possibilities are endless!